# How to switch Facebook page to "new experience"

Tags: facebook

This may be the wrong forum, but I do not know of any more suitable (there's definitely nothing on Facebook itself).

I want to post on someone else's Facebook page as my own page.  It is possible, I've done it before.

But it seems now only possible for pages that have been switched to the "new pages experience".

I manage several pages, but only one of them appears in the "post as" list.  That is the one that has somehow been switched.

For love nor money I cannot find out how to get the other pages switched over.

Help, please.

Comment: If there's a better Stack Exchange forum for this type of question, please feel free to move it there.

Comment: I currently have the same problem. It appears there's no way to switch from classic still.